# She has a disease, I'm just the Carrier

Tags: riddle, cipher

> Questionably philanthropic,
>   Her existence has been quite the topic.
>
> > Should she go? Should she stay?
> >     Not a gift, either way.
> >     Should she stay? Should she go?
> >     Either way, 'twill be slow!
>
> Her charity's surely iconic.

She is:

[image: hint]

> > Tell me who she is and how the answer relates to the riddle.

**EDIT:**
 -Clarified that the translated code IS the answer.
 -Asked that relevance to the riddle be included in the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The barcode is the postal code from the bottom of letters and translates to:

> US Postal Service

Reasoning:

> Using the information found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSTNET), you can turn each of the barcodes into numbers.

The numbers read:

> 85 83
>  80 111 115 116 97 108
>  83 101 114 118 105 99 101

Translated, from ASCII, this is the above answer.

This matches the riddle, because:

> There have been debates and discussions, in recent years as to the postal service being necessary anymore.  You can find a number of related articles by searching google for "[Should the US Postal Service Be Abolished](https://www.google.com/#q=should+the+us+postal+service+be+abolished)".

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you translated that barcode?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSTNET

Comment: @GordonAllocman That is the link I used. I also added a little explanation in the post

Comment: Nicely done, decoding the code. I was somewhat unclear, but the answer *is* the decoded message.  I edited the question to reflect this and to ask for a bit more elaboration before accepting an answer.  +1